# How do I check if ydn.db database is ready for use?

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, ydn-db

I can successfully create an indexeddb database and load data into it. I can also read data from this database from the same page. I then try and read from the database from another page on my site.

```
db = new ydn.db.Storage('test');
db.keys('items').done(function(d) {
    alert(d);
});
```

This does not work. I just get an empty result. However if I enter the above code into the javascript console of Chrome directly it does work. After looking around it seems that the database may not be ready. So I try this.

```
db = new ydn.db.Storage('test');
db.addEventListener('ready', function() {
    db.keys('items').done(function(d) {
        alert(d);
    });
});
```

This however gives me the the following error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The error is show for the following line of code.

```
db.addEventListener('ready', function() {
```

I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening database connection is an asynchronous operation. This `ready` event listener is invoked when database is connected and **after** necessary schema changes are made. This is the **first asynchronous function call** make by the database instance.

If database opening fail, the callback is invoke with `error` event object. Multiple listener can be added. Heavy database write operation should invoke after this ready event handler. Alternatively `ready` event can be listen through `DOM` event listener pattern.

You can add database ready event listener in similar way:

```
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('test');
db.onReady(function(e) {
  if (e) {
    if (e.target.error) {
      console.log('Error due to: ' + e.target.error.name + ' ' + e.target.error.message);
    }
    throw e;
  }
  db.put('statement1', large_data);
});
```